# why are my python threads blocking each other

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

My current predicament is that I attempted to make a blocking web serving script non blocking to allow for more than one download to take place at any one time but currently it will hang and wait for the first download to complete before starting the second. Before you go out of your way to down vote this because the answer is odious please know that this is my first ever python script and I am self teaching.

In the example below I only post a single "ConnectionProcesser" Because they all contain the same code 
if you need more code please just ask

The script has 3 dependinces

```
import socket  # Networking support
import signal  # Signal support (server shutdown on signal receive)
import threading #to make the thing run more than one at a time
```

Please note that the script has been edited and quite a bit of the code is missing but I believe that it is unrelated to the problem.

```
 def ConnectionProcessorC(self):
     connC, AddressC = self.socket.accept()
     print("C Got connection from:", AddressC)
     DataRecivedC = connC.recv(1024) #receive data from client
     DataRecivedC = bytes.decode(DataRecivedC) #decode it to string
     print(DataRecivedC)
     RequestMethod = DataRecivedC.split(' ')[0]
     print ("C Method: ", RequestMethod)
     if (RequestMethod == 'GET') | (RequestMethod == 'HEAD'):
         Response_Headers = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'
        # Current_Date = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        # Response_Headers += 'Date: ' + current_date +'\n'
         Response_Headers += 'Server: Moes-Python-Server\n'
         Response_Headers += 'Connection: close\n\n'  # signal that the conection wil be closed after complting the request
         Server_Response =  Response_Headers.encode() # return headers for GET and HEAD
         file_handler = open('/usr/share/nginx/html/100mb.dump','rb')
         Response_Content = file_handler.read() # read file content
         file_handler.close()
         URL=DataRecivedC.split(' ')
         URL = URL[1] # get 2nd element
         #Response_Content="<html><body><p>Charlie TEStin this stuff yehURL:"+URL+"</p></body></html>"
         Server_Response +=  Response_Content 

         connC.send(Server_Response)
         print ("C Closing connection with client")
     else:
         print("C Unknown HTTP request method:", RequestMethod)

     connC.close()
     return 
 def Distrabuteconnections(self):
     A=0
     """ Main loop awaiting connections """
     while True:
         print ("Awaiting New connection")
         self.socket.listen(10) # maximum number of queued connections #changed to 1 from 3 to try and prevent waiting after closing for ther que to clean up 

         if (A==0):
             ConnectionProcessorA = threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorA())
             ConnectionProcessorA.start()
             A=1
         elif (A==1):
             ConnectionProcessorB = threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorB())
             ConnectionProcessorB.start()
             A=2
         else:
             ConnectionProcessorC = threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorC())
             ConnectionProcessorC.start()
             A=0
```

I think that the problem could be solved by changing while true to something that loops 3 times instead of one.

Comment: Switching from threads to subprocesses should solve it

Comment: But why do I need subprocesses is there a reason? and don't they run slower?

Comment: Subprocesses MAY take a bit longer to start and have higher memory footprint but there is no reason why would they be slower. And reason would be GIL, which seems to interfere with threads. This doesn't take place in subprocesses.

Comment: wont it affect global variables shared between threads Do you know where someone like me could start converting this to sub processes? some links or a short example of what needs to be done would be nice and i think that i can still do this with friends so I am going to leave this question open and hope that someone comes along with a solution

Comment: FYI, for people coming across this question in the future, **the problem here has nothing to do with the GIL.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a reference to the method you wish to start in a thread. Instead, you are calling the thread, and passing the data returned from that method to the `threading.Thread()` call.

In short your code should become:

```
     if (A==0):
         ConnectionProcessorA = threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorA)
         ConnectionProcessorA.start()
         A=1
     elif (A==1):
         ConnectionProcessorB = threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorB)
         ConnectionProcessorB.start()
         A=2
     else:
         ConnectionProcessorC = threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorC)
         ConnectionProcessorC.start()
         A=0
```

Note the removal of the brackets after `self.ConnectionProcessorA` etc. This passes a reference to the method to start in the thread, which the threading module will call itself.

Note, it is recommended to store a reference to the thread you create so that it doesn't get garbage collected. I would thus recommend your code becomes:

```
     if (A==0):
         self.cpa_thread= threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorA)
         self.cpa_thread.start()
         A=1
     elif (A==1):
         self.cpb_thread= threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorB)
         self.cpb_thread.start()
         A=2
     else:
         self.cpc_thread= threading.Thread(target=self.ConnectionProcessorC)
         self.cpc_thread.start()
         A=0
```

Comment: I tried your code it all it did was run ConnectionProcessorA over and over so i could not test if it works or not

Comment: I think what i need to do is to remove the while true and replace it with a call from inside the thread when the connection is created so the script does not just keep creating threads like it does now

Comment: I would have expected all 3 threads to still run, but yes it is best to just spawn a thread each time a connection is made. Potentially you could call `socket.accept()` in the main thread, and pass the `connX` and `AddressX` variables to the thread. If you need help changing the architecture of your program, it might be best to post a new question with a **minimilistic working example** of what you are doing now so that people can actually run some code that simulates what you are doing.